# Finer control over Angular rendering

Tags: angular, ngrx, busyindicator

I have what should likely be a very common scenario:

I display a busy-wait spinner until the NgRx state has signaled an operation is complete.

*In the template:*

```
<my-loading-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></my-loading-spinner>
```

*In the component backing code:*

```
this.loading$ = store.pipe(select(operationStatus), map(loadingFn));
```

... where the `loadingFn` function maps the `operationState` NgRx state value to a boolean.

The result data for this view is loaded into the NgRx state right alongside the `operationStatus`, in the very same call in the reducer:

```
return set(
        STATUS, EntityStatus.loadingSuccess, // the operationState
        myEntityAdapter.addAll(action.payload.tokens, state) // the data
      ) as MyEntityState;
```

This result data is a lengthy object list, that goes through a sort in the component, then is rendered via an `*ngFor` with non-trivial content.

So it is not surprising that my problem ensues: the busy-wait spinner goes away noticeably before the rendered data table appears on screen.

Is there any type of "some-specific-data-has-finished-rendering" event that could be monitored so that I can make my busy-wait spinner stay around until the data table has completely rendered?

**2019.03.01 Update**

I attempted the approach suggested by @ConnorsFan : I changed my template to use a new non-observable `*ngIf="viewLoading"` initialized as `public viewLoading = true;` Then in the subscription body I simply set it false:

```
this.dataRows.changes.subscribe(() => {
    this.viewLoading = false;
});
```

I tried this approach but it did not make a difference; the spinner still was hidden prematurely. Perhaps I did not apply the recipe correctly? I should note that this threw a runtime error as well, the always-challenging `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` (*Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'*)

Comment: Can you do something like `*ngIf="(loading$ | async) && !items"` where items is the array used by `ngFor`. Perform any sorting work before items is assigned a value.

Comment: Intriguing thought @cgTag; I will give that a go tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help @ccTag; the list of items in the expression is available too soon apparently.

Answer (score 1):

When you have element generated by an `ngFor` loop:

```
<div #dataRow *ngFor="let item of items"> ... </div>
```

you can get the `QueryList` of elements with `ViewChildren` and be notified that the elements have been rendered by subscribing to the `QueryList.changes` event:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
...    
export class MyComponent {

  @ViewChildren("dataRow") dataRows: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  dataRowsRendered: boolean;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataRows.changes.subscribe(() => {
      // Do something after the data rows have been rendered
      console.log(`${this.dataRows.length} data rows have been rendered`);
      this.dataRowsRendered = true;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried this approach but to no avail--see my notes added to the question above.

Comment: If you use `console.log(this.dataRows.length)`, how many rows are reported in the `QueryList.changes` callback? Also: can we see the relevant parts of the `ngFor` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think @ConnorsFan is the correct answer. I didn't think of using `@ViewChildren()`.

You could modify his answer to update the `loading$` observable.

```
@ViewChildren("dataRow") dataRows: QueryList<ElementRef>;

this.loading$ = combineLatest(
     store.pipe(select(operationStatus), map(loadingFn)),
     this.dataRows.changes.pipe(mapTo(this.dataRows.length === 0)
).pipe(map(([loading,rows])=>loading || rows));
```

I would also recommend adding the style `display: none` to the `ngFor` element while it's loading, and then removing it based up `loading$`. This will remove the display *after* QueryList emits that it's changed. So when the list is shown it should already exist in the DOM fully rendered.